# Lighting:textArea minLength not wokring

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, long-text-area

Component :

```
            <lightning:textarea aura:id="commentId" name="comments" required="true" value="{!v.case.Comments}"
                                placeholder="Enter comments here"
                                label="Comments"
                                messageWhenValueMissing="Comments required" minLength="3" messageWhenBadInput="Min 3 characters needed"/>
```

Controller side I am validating this as :

```
var checkCommentsValid = component.find("commentId");
checkCommentsValid.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
```

But still it does not show any message when character is less than 3. Though required field works fine, but minLength does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IDE generated wrong suggestion, it should be `minlength="3"`, with small `l`.

Answer (score 0):

Ligthtning is case sensitive as per docs use `minlength` instead <s>`minLength`</s> use small cases

```
        <lightning:textarea aura:id="commentId" name="comments" required="true" value="{!v.case.Comments}"
                            placeholder="Enter comments here"
                            label="Comments"
                            messageWhenValueMissing="Comments required" minLength="3" messageWhenBadInput="Min 3 characters needed"/>
```